# Nonlinear ODE - possible transformations or analytical techniques?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, elliptic-functions

I work with a problem that gives me a nonlinear 3rd order ODE. The equation in question is:

$f'''(x) - \alpha f(x) f''(x) + \alpha f'(x)^2 + k f'(x)=0$

The coefficient $k$ always turns out to be an integer, and $\alpha$ is real and positive. I attempted transforming the equation to one of the Weierstrass (elliptical) differential equation forms, but without any success. Of course, there is a trivial solution $f(x) = -\frac{k}{\alpha}x + C_0$. Is there a method to find other analytical solutions (if any, i.e.)?

Comment: You can easily transform this equation into a 2nd order ODE by using a substitution such as $t(x)=f'(x)$ then we have $t''(x) - \alpha t'(x) + \alpha (t(x))^2 + k t(x)=0$ but I do not know how to solve such an equation either.

Comment: For cases where $\alpha f'(x)^2$ is small compared to other terms then good approximations can be found using perturbation theory (e.g. solve the ODE with this term zero and then solve the linear equation with this term being computed using the previous found solution)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, for the second term is a mixed derivative. Correcting now. Simple order reduction transformations does not work.

Comment: @Winther I would like to keep that as the last option. Is there any mathematical theorem that guarantees non-trivial solutions for such non-linear ODE's? If there is, I guess perturbation methods should be a reasonable final choice.

Comment: You have to separate between solutions and analytical solutions (i.e. closed form in elementary functions). There are theorems that can guarantee existence and uniqueness of solutions of non-linear equations on certain sets. However only a very small class of non-linear ODEs have analytical solutions.

Comment: One general technique is to present $f(x)$ as a formal power series: $f(x)=\Sigma a_{n}x^{n}$. Then $f'$ $f''$ and $f'''$ can be similarly expressed, as can the products. Then a formal expression can be formed for the $x^{n}$ th term, which might be simplifiable. The theorems will now be about whether the final expression converges. Also to get some idea about some special cases one can set parameters to zero. For example the limiting case $\alpha =0$ has a simple closed form solution: $f(x)=\frac{A}{\sqrt(-k)} exp^{\sqrt{-k}x} - \frac{B}{\sqrt(-k)} exp^{-\sqrt{-k}x}$